# For each loop passvarible to other for each loop meteor

Tags: meteor

I need to pass the variable to helper function Please help me.

```
<div class="sidebar">
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" style="display: block; position: static;">

                            {{#each search_family_list}}
                                <li class="dropdown-submenu active"><a href="#" id="{{ family_id }}" class="family_type"><img src="" />{{ description }}</a>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">

                                        {{#each material_list}}
                                            <li><a href="/search/57/atlanta/">atlanta</a></li>
                                        {{/each}}

                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            {{/each}}

                            </ul>
                        </div>
```

In the above example i need to pass the family_id to the material_list helper function.

```
Template.header.helpers({
        material_list: function ()
        {
            return Session.get("search_family_list");
        }
    });
```

Please help me.

Comment: And what is in your session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is likely you can access family_id as a property of `this` inside your helper.

```
Template.header.helpers({   
  material_list: function () {
      var family_id = this.family_id;

      return Session.get("search_family_list");
  }
});
```

The function context of a template helper can be used to access the current data context.